# sudo apt-get build-dep lib32gcc1 (not working on Ubuntu 14.04.5)

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

I have to resolve package dependencies (I need to Install AMD graphics R7 M370).

I am getting this error. I am new on Ubuntu, guide me please..

```
sudo apt-get install build-dep lib32gcc1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'gccgo-4.9' as source package instead of 'lib32gcc1'
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 7.11~1) but it is not going to be installed
 libmirplatformgraphics-mesa : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for lib32gcc1 could not be satisfied.
```

Comment: Use text instead of image of the error. Use ctrl-c and ctrl-v

Comment: Please check it now

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/918085/error-processing-package-fglrx-package-fglrx-is-not-configured-yet#comment1448301_918085 Bottom line: You can stop trying to install drivers that are no longer compatible. Either use the open source `radeon` (Ubuntu default, no user intervention needed) or try the proprietary `amdgpu-pro` directly from AMD if available for your card.

Comment: Why exactly do you believe you need to install the *build dependencies of* `lib32gcc1`? Regardless, it looks like your actual issue is related to conflicting version requirements for `libgbm1` rather than anything to do with `lib32gcc1`

Comment: @steeldriver OP is trying to install `fglrx`, that's why. Just look at the other questions.

Comment: @MichaelBay  First I tried amdgpu-pro on Ubuntu 16.04 as it was available of their website i.e. http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx.                                                                      bt after that when I restart my system it stucks at login. and didn't worked. So someone refered me to go with ubuntu 14. SO i installed this version .and its not working too.

Comment: If the default open source driver works, keep it.

Comment: default is working but I have to run simulations on Gazebo MORSE etc. and at default its FPS decreases to 9 or 10. which is quite low. I want FPS 50 +